# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker queue behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

Using Elastic Beanstalk I create a worker 1.1 tier (64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 1.9.3) from the Management Console. When it comes to configuring the worker details I opt for "Autogenerate Queue". When I do so two SQS queues are generated (worker and dead letter), but the "Worker queue URL" for my worker instance is set to the dead letter queue url. I would have thought it should be the worker queue? If I attempt to change it to the worker queue in the worker config, both queues are deleted (worker and dead letter). Can anyone tell me if this is normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

When you elect the Auto Generated Queue it creates two queue. One is the main and other is for Dead Letter Queue. By default your worker instance listen to the main queue. The dead letter queue is configured in the main queue configuration. If there are many message considered dead not able to process then the main queue puts in to dead letter. Worker queue does not d